# Array printing out same cell over and over

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having a user enter data First Name, Last Name, and Number. The problem is when I print out the array, it will only print out the last entered data.

For example if a user enters: (F,V 12345) 
              (L,K  2345)
             (R,G  4555)
//Initials used instead of names

The program would print out:

R,G  4555
R,G  4555
R,G  4555

Datab.java

```
 public Datab()
{
    first = null;
    last = null;
    cell = null;
}

public Datab(String f, String l, String c)
{
    first=f;
    last=l;
    cell=c;

}
public static String getFirst(Datab friends)
{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter First name: ");
    first = kb.next();
    return first;

}
public static String getLast(Datab friends)
{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Last name: ");
    last = kb.next();


    return last;  
} 
public static String getCell(Datab friends)
{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Cell Number: ");
    cell = kb.next();

    return cell;

}



 public String toString(){




 return (first + " ,"+" "+ last + " "+ cell);



   }

}
```

DBMS.java

```
Datab[] friends = new Datab[n];


    for (int i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {
        friends[i] = new Datab();
        System.out.println("\nFilling object #: " + (i + 1));



        friends[i].getFirst(friends[i]);

        friends[i].getLast(friends[i]);
        friends[i].getCell(friends[i]);


    }

for(int x=0; x<friends.length; x++){

            System.out.println(friends[x]);
        }
```

Comment: friends[0].getFirst(friends[0]); why it is get?? it should be set... and you are manually setting index 0 instead of using i.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my part. It's supposed to be friends[i].

Comment: friends[i] = new Datab(); shouldn't here be applied the explicit constructor? where are you defining you object fields?

Comment: You are not creating any instances. Simply you are updating the fields with new values. Use instance fields instead of static.

Answer (score 1):

Reason you have defined your variable `first, last, cell` as static.

You should remove static and make it is instance specific. Same applies for method as well.

When you make a variable as static, you just have one instance of the same and whatever you assigned value at last, is the one you are going to see and hence you see the same value being printed irrespective of what you assigned before.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I applied your answer and removed the static identifiers. Now the output is the last object and the others print out null. Am I missing something?

Comment: paste your updated code in your question so we could look at it.

Comment: Disregard my last comment. I had the friends array index set to zero instead of i.

Answer (score 0):

Variables **`first`, `last`, `cell`** are static. Also, the methods **`getFirst()`, `getLast()`, `getCell()`** defined for initializing the variables are static.

There is only one single copy created for static members(variables and members) for all the instances of a class. So, in your case, all the instances of class Datab, i.e., friends[] **refers to same copy of variables** first, last, cell.

**Removing `static` keyword** from variable declaration and methods will solve the problem, as all the instances of Datab will point to different variables.